# How to export large data from ArcMap to use in Python/R

Tags: arcmap, csv

The number of rows in my shapefile attributes greater than 65535. I can't export the table to Excel.
Is there any way to generate the file to CSV to any other format which will be convenient to use in Python/R?

Comment: Excel is not a large data handler. In fact, I generally don't want it installed anywhere near GIS data. Please [Edit] your Question to state what the source format is, how many rows and columns are in this "very big" table, and what the geometry type is. Note that "best" questions are often closed as *opinion-based*.

Comment: Elaborate what do you mean by very big data......

Comment: The number of rows in my shapefile attributes greater than 65535. I can't export the data to excel. My question: is there anyway to export the data in .csv format so that I can use it in python/R?

Comment: ASCII is fine as a transfer format, but it's generally a worst-case use format. Far better to let R use the source shapefile, or use file geodatabase or GeoPackage, which support a spatial index.  You generally have to cross ten million rows to earn the title "large", and 100m for "very large", though width and complexity (which you didn't provide) can have an impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know python, you should have no problem doing it with `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` and `csv.writer()`. Something like this:

```py
import csv
w1 = open('C:/path/to/output.csv', 'w')
w2 = csv.writer(w1)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('your_layer_name', ['LIST', 'OF', 'FIELDS', 'TO', 'OUTPUT']) as c:
    w2.writerow(c.fields)  # Write header row
    for row in c:
        w2.writerow(row)  # Write each record
del w2
w1.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

[Copy Rows:](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-rows.htm)

> Writes the rows from an input table, table view, feature class, or
> feature layer to a new table. If a selection is defined on a feature
> class or feature layer in ArcMap, only the selected rows are copied
> out.

Just specify the output filename `something.csv`